# What is the best way to write appropriate validations for domain models in DDD?

Tags: validation, domain-driven-design

I've heard about different ways to write validation for domain models, So I want to know which of them is better in the domain-driven-design.

1. Some people say that it's better to validate the domain model's data before initializing it (it means that validations should be run on the related DTOs).
2. Some people say that it's better to validate the domain model's data after initializing it (it means that validations should be run on the initialized entity or domain model).
3. Also, some people say that all the validations should be run inside of the entity (exactly in setters or constructors)

Indeed, I was used to writing a combination of the above validations, but now I'm not sure about that. Which of them is common and basically more sensible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In domain driven design, what you are most likely to see are "value objects" that guarantee certain constraints are met during initialization, therefore in the constructor of the value object itself.  Since values are (by convention) *immutable* over their lifetime, you wouldn't normally include setters in their interface.

DTOs serve a different purpose, but are mechanically similar to value objects in many ways.  So you might see validation in the DTO *in addition to* validation within the domain model.

You don't normally have *value* validation in your entities.  An entity is typically holds references to values (which validate themselves) or other local entities (validated elsewhere), so checking that the references are correct is in bounds (ie, check for null).